# Is the sentence clear enough without past perfect

Tags: past-tense, past-vs-past-perfect

> In fact Rich sent all the goods he had on hold for me but he **forgot** to include in the parcel the book and the problem is that he moved just after sending the goods and did not take it with him.

Would **had forgotten** be possible? I think it is not necessary because the meaning is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no need for past perfect here.  "Had forgotten" would possible but not required for this meaning.